# Run different Tests in parallel (while running each Test’s TestCase sequentially)

Tags: testing, automated-tests, nunit, nunit-3.0

i try to run few test cases in parallel and it don't work well.
i want run in parallel test cases but each test case that run in parallel run with test case from anoter test and not with test case from same test.

i have 2 tests in same class and for each test i have a few test cases:

```
 [TestFixture] 
 [Parallelizable(ParallelScope.All)] 
 [Category("example_category")]
 public class example
 {
    [Test] 
    [TestCase(param1, param2)]   
    [TestCase(param1, param2)] 
    public void test1(object param1, object param2){
        // do some stuff
    }

    [Test] 
    [TestCase(param1, param2)]   
    [TestCase(param1, param2)] 
    public void test2(object param1, object param2){
        // do some stuff
    } 
 }
```

now all tests run in parallel but i get a lot of errors, what i want to do is run in parallel test cases from another tests.
for example:
i want test case from test1 run in parallel with test case from test2, but now 2 test case of test1 run in parallel and i want to avoid from this.
how i can fix my code to do it right?

**this tests is not a selenium tests, only backend tests so i don't use driver.**

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to guarantee the behavior you want is to put the two test methods in separate fixtures. In that case, you would not want to keep using `ParallelScope.All` on the fixtures, since that would allow the fixtures to run together. You should use `ParallelScope.Children` in that case.